# How can I run a Windows program without granting it any Internet access?

Tags: wine

So I have CrossOver on Linux, but since this is basically the project with which I also help the Wine folks and virtually all of the fundamentals are applicable to both, I am asking under [wine](/questions/tagged/wine).

Is it possible to start a Windows program under Wine in such a way that it has no access to the Internet at all?

So far I have come up empty-handed when it came to this. I was thinking about writing my own shared object in order to tinker around by way of `LD_PRELOAD` but that sort of thing is anyway off-topic here.

Is there any way from a pure user perspective to achieve what I want? Could kernel namespaces be used for this in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could unshare the network namespace:

```
sudo unshare -n -- su your_user -c your_command
```

Comment: Will `unshare` suffice to make it completely unavailable? I guess the idea with namespaces wasn't too far off the mark ...

Comment: The current stack will be unavailable. A new one, with just loopback, will be given to the process. You can test it yourself by running ping or trying to connect. Note that you are not just blocking internet, you will not be able to connect to even your own local servers over IP. (and yes, you were pretty close to the soution).

Comment: Excellent, I think this fits my bill perfectly. Now I just need to figure out how I can put this into a convenient form (i.e. so that not _everything_ running under Wine will be affected. Separating by bottle is fine. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 5):

I can think of this convoluted way: create a separate user account, e.g. wineuser and run your Windows application under it. You might want to run this command under your user account: `xhost +SI:localuser:wineuser` (to allow the wine user to access your graphical session) and export the DISPLAY variable under the wine account, e.g. `export DISPLAY=:0`

To limit this user access to the Internet run this command/add this iptables rule:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner wineuser -j DROP
```

(Or you can use REJECT instead of DROP).

---

You could also try OpenSnitch: https://itsfoss.com/opensnitch-firewall-linux/ or LAF (Linux Application Firewall): https://github.com/matrix-ac/LAF

Comment: Interesting idea with a slight detour. Thanks.

Comment: A separate group would do too, and you won't need have display access problem either.